# 80's/ 90s Story - Lost space ship with invisibly fast aliens is discovered

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Seeking some help identifying a story I read a while back and forgot the title.

The plot includes a lost space ship holding a crew of aliens that move too quickly to be visible.

It's an older publication, probably 80's or 90's timeframe.

Some additional details I recall: (1) the space hero is a cyborg, or at least his arm is mechanical, (2) the aliens are the last remaining from a race of warlike, empire builders. They never met their conquests in person, but always broadcast their images to hide the fact they were so fast as to be invisible.

Answer (score 3):

This one is a slight stretch now that I've researched it more, but is there any chance you're thinking of "[All Cats are Gray](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29019/29019-h/29019-h.htm)" by Andre Norton? It's older than you remember (published in a 1953 issue of *Fantastic Universe Science Fiction*), but it involves a derelict space ship and aliens that are invisible to most in the group. However, it's not a matter of speed, but a matter of coloration. Here's [the summary from an Andre Norton fan site](http://andre-norton-books.com/index.php/worlds-of-andre/short-stories-by-andre/30-all-cats-are-gray):

> Steena of the Spaceways is a non-descript woman with gray hair and wears nothing but gray and even appears to be gray. She is a drifter and spends her free time in the stellar-port bar of whatever port she happens to work. She rarely speaks and just listens to the talk of other spacers. When she does decide to say something, those spacers listen closely. She once told a spacer about the Jovan moon rites, and this warning later saves the man's life. A shone that she identified as an unworked piece of a precious gem became the fortunes of ten men. Each man has tried to pay her back, but she refused everything, until a grateful spacer gives her a gray tomcat named Bat, and the two have been inseparable ever since.
>
> When a destitute spacer named Cliff Moran comes into the bar, Steena joins him at his table. This sobers him up because Sheena never chooses company when she can be alone. All she says to him is that the Empress of Mars is due to appear soon. The Empress of Mars is a pleasure ship carrying untold wealth. It was left in a derelict orbit when all its passengers and the entire crew abandoned the ship and disappeared without a trace fifty years earlier.
>   Cliff leaves to find the Empress, and Steena and Bat have stowed away on his ship—presumably in cash in on one of her own tips. Their presence does not bother Cliff; it just adds to the surprises Steena has already given him.
>
> Once on board the cruise ship, Cliff goes straight to the control room, and Steena and Bat explore the rest of the ship. Steena walks into one room filled with silks, crystal, and jeweled containers. In the dressing mirror, she sees spider-silk covering the bed and a pile of gems on top of the spider-silk. Then one piece of jewelry moves. Bat flattens threateningly at the heap on the bed. He crouches and follows the invisible alien out of the cabin and down the corridor.
>
> Sheena follows Bat to the control room where Cliff continues to work on the engine. She sees something against Cliff’s shoulder and Bat snarls. With her photographic memory, she remembers something. She takes off her gray spaceall and drapes it across the nearest chair. Steena tells Cliff to throw his blaster to her while Bat moves the invisible thing toward her. She fires at the spaceall on the chair, and the stench that fills the room signals that she hit her target.

And the reveal...

> Cliff is dumbfounded and asks several questions. Steena explains that the alien creature was a shade of gray that was beyond human sight. She and Bat were both color-blind and could only see shades of gray, but only Bat could see the alien. Steam was able to see a type of reflection of the creature when it crossed in front of their gray spacealls.

....

> They check the ship and find it free of any other aliens. Steena and Cliff make their-fortune when they bring in the Empress, and they fall in love. Their family of three live in colorful comfort afterward. ~ DB

Comment: Some additional details I recall: (1) the space hero is a cyborg, or at least his arm is mechanical, (2) the aliens are the last remaining from a race of warlike, empire builders.  They never met their conquests in person, but always broadcast their images to hide the fact they were so fast as to be invisible.

Answer (score 3):

In case Fuzzy's answer is not it, may I suggest "Supermind" by van Vogt?

I don' recall aliens, but the basic premise is that as people grow more intelligent they eventually gain the power of "freedom of movement". This makes them so fast that normal humans cannot see them. The super-intelligent live on other planets in the solar system, and I believe the plot starts on a spaceship.

The protagonist of the story starts off as a "normal human", but through interactions with various forces he becomes ultra-intelligent and gains these abilities. There is a constant battle between those that already have these IQs, and various others on a scale from 100 to 10,000.

It is not entirely unlike Slan (or other van Vogt novels for that matter) in basic outline. IIRC it was published in 1979, so *just* about the age you're referring to.

Comment: The book was definitely more Star Wars than Star Trek.  Explore lost space ship with evil crew that is slowly waking up from a very long hibernation.